# Conditional formatting for images in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I put together a document where an image will load based on the result of a range of cell info (i.e. if cell 1 is a, cell 2 is b and cell 3 is c, cell 4 is image 1, etc). It works well, however I'm trying to make a 2nd column with a separate set of images based on the same fields (in a separate cell, obviously) and I'm running into an issue where excel isn't showing the image? I can define the name and all that, but it just shows the handles of the image, not the image itself.

Tools>Options>Show Objects is checked and I tried selecting the handles and choosing 'Bring to Front', but no dice. I'm thinking this is an easy answer but an hour and a half of tinkering and multiple google searches later and here I am. Anyone have any thoughts? I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Things you could do:-
Have you tried getting your first code to modify the picture of the second picture?
Have you tried changing the spreadsheet view to page mode or another to see if it behaves differently.
I'm guessing!

Comment: Yup, no dice. Here's the code in cell A4:
=IF(AND(B1="Horizontal",B2="No",B3="Left"),"Picture 1"
That loads anything defined as Picture 1 just fine. If I copy that code and paste it into A5 and name a new picture "Picture 6":
=IF(AND(B1="Horizontal",B2="No",B3="Left"),"Picture 6"
Then all the cell loads is the word Picture 6 and not the photo itself. Totally unsure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is actually very simple in principal.

In essence, if you insert a picture object it shows a picture.  If you select the picture and type a cell reference (eg =A1, or =A1:D1) into the formula bar, you enter a formula to be used by the picture.  This formula causes the picture to "look for" any shape objects that are positioned over the cell(s) used in the formula.  It the displays the part of the pictures that are over the cells in the formula reference.  Capiche!?

An example how the above is used in a real situation is explained very well here:  [http://www.cga-pdnet.org/pdf/VLOOKUPforPictures.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20150513064554/http://www.cga-pdnet.org/pdf/VLOOKUPforPictures.pdf)